# XSLT 1.0 code flow

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I was wondering how code is executed when you're in a template and call another template that retrieves a value and then you continue processing the first template and using that value capture by the other template. Can anyone provide a working example of this setup?

An example might be:

```
<xsl:template name="test">

    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="boolean(.)">

            <xsl:variable name="list" select="'want to store this and return to previous template'"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>

    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">

<file_item_nbr>
     <xsl:call-template name="test">
 </xsl:call-template>
     <xsl:value-of select="$test"/>
</file_item_nbr>

</xsl:template>
```

My real case goes much further than what I've displayed as an example. I want to be able to get the parent nodes number after the hyphen(-) and pass that integer value back to the original template to then increment the variable by a specific number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple variable scoping problem.

Variables are scoped to their immediate parent. They do not exist outside of it.

Just reverse your approach. You want the variable *contents* depend a template call, after all. The variable itself must be declared in the same spot where you want to use it.

```
<xsl:template name="test">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="boolean(.)">
      <xsl:value-of select="'want to store this and return to previous template'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="'maybe I want to store something else here'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <file_item_nbr>

    <xsl:variable name="result">
      <xsl:call-template name="test" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="$result"/>
  </file_item_nbr>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that the current node does not change when you do `xsl:call-template>`, i.e. the meaning of `.` stays the same as in the calling template.

---

The two ways to modify a result of `<xsl:call-template>` are either

```
<xsl:variable name="temp">
  <xsl:call-template name="test" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="result">
  <xsl:value-of select="$temp + 2" />
</xsl:variable>
```

or, a bit nicer by nesting variables:

```
<xsl:variable name="result">
  <xsl:variable name="temp">
    <xsl:call-template name="test" />
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="$temp + 2" />
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Is there a way to then take $result + 2 and store that to a variable?

Comment: There is, just not *directly*. You have to use a temp variable. See modified answer. (Note that variables are read-only. They cannot be changed once they are assigned. So there is no way to increment a value in-place.)

Comment: Now let's say I use your last box of code several times within a template, will temp be unique to every use or will it hold it's value as it's being called different times?

Comment: See the second paragraph in my answer. ;)

Comment: Would the immediate parent be the template?

Comment: No, the immediate parent is the XML node that the variable is a child of. In that case, the other variable.

Comment: But if I use your second to last code block, then that should work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "that". Yes, if you nest the variables, `temp` will be unique to every use. I had hoped you draw this conclusion yourself, but if you insist I spell it out for you. ;)

Comment: It would have been easy to test your assumptions and prove or disprove them. (At least I believe that doing trial-and-error runs to test a hypothesis helps you understand better that just being told the facts alone would.)